# which verb can correctly replace "[got] a merit in maths olympiad at school level"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which of the following sentences are correct (if any)?

1. **Awarded** a merit in maths olympiad at school level
2. **Received** a merit in maths olympiad at school level
3. **Endowed with** a merit in maths olympiad at school level

Comment: 'achieved' is another possibility. It makes it  sound as though you were responsible rather than the people who gave you the certificate.

Comment: Given that "merit* means high marks you might also say you ***earned*** a merit ...

Comment: What is "a merit"?  In AmE, "merit" is not a count noun (although, oddly enough, "demerit" is!)

Answer (score 1):

Either the first (sounds grander) or the second (more 'everyday').

Not the third.  Individuals are naturally endowed with attributes and abilities.  Individauls and institutions can be endowed by benefactors who, typically, give them large amounts of money.  An endowment is conferred rather than 'won'.

Comment: I'm going to upvote because you said "won" which is a great answer.

Comment: @James: I don't understand that. In *English*, nobody ever "wins" high marks in exams.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, my misunderstanding of "a merit".  Won makes no sense.  I thought a merit was an award of some kind (book token, likely).

Comment: But in an Olympics, people "win" medals, and are "awarded" medals, even though in fact they earned (and merited) the medals by their efforts.

Comment: The point at issue seems to be balance between whether a 'prize' (exam mark, cup, money ...) is bestowed or seized from others competetively.